# SSRS - Ignore nulls when doing alternate row color (in matrix)

Tags: reporting-services

usually outside of a matrix column group I would use =IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "Transparent", "LightGrey") to alternate row colors.

But when using a matrix column group the same expression alternates the columns in that group instead of the rows, so have used this instead
=IIF(Runningvalue(MAX(Fields!My_column.Value),CountDistinct,"my_column_group") mod 2,"Transparent", "LightGrey")

The problem now is that when there is a null or blank value it ignores it and the row colours do not alternate, as demonstrated in the photo
[image]

Is there a way to include a ways of ignoring NULL values in the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little messy as it means adding a new column and then setting the width so you cannot see it but it does work.

1. In your matrix add a new column inside your row group.
2. Make a note of the name of the textbox that was just created or rename it to something better (in my case I called it `bgCol`)
3. Set the expression for this textbox to `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, Nothing, "LightGrey")`
4. Click the row header so the entire row is selected and set the backgroundcolor property to `=ReportItems!bgCol.Value` (or whatever the new textbox is called)
5. Shrink the column width to it's minimum so you can't see it.

Comment: Not sure why, but this no longer works, at least not on 2016 Microsoft Version 13.0.5108.50

Comment: Make sure you set the **Value Expression** of the hidden column, not the background.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately, I did. I found the issue: the query for whatever reason isn't able to return the column values in question. From what I can see, it just pretends they don't exist for NULL values. This is before it even hits tablix. I'm still not sure whether the problem is in SQL Server or Report Builder though.

Comment: I've tested and it works fine on SSRS 2016. I'm using Visual Studio rather than Report Builder but it's just an RDL file at the end of the day so that shoudl make no difference. SQL can't make a difference here either as it does not affect the way the solution works.

Comment: To be very clear, yes your method would work, but it is highly dependent on the query results. For unknown reasons, certain queries to SQL Server from Report Builder do not return all of a row's columns. Not even a NULL value is returned, so your VBA won't be able to even examine the value because there is none returned. ie There is nothing wrong with your solution. It just doesn't work in my edge case

Comment: You could add a static column to the query, but all datasets return all columns, they just have to and there has to be a value or a null, you can't have any other scenario, it's just a query, nothing special happens in SSRS. If this doesn't work for whatever reason, post a new question with sample data included and reference this question, I'd be happy to look at it.